# How to find closest to zero number in a pair of numbers?

Tags: min

Of course, there is always:

```
if abs(x) < abs(y) { return x; } else { return y; }
```

But I wonder if there is more optimal solutions to the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "optimal?" Is this running too slowly?

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following

```
   function(a,b) {
     return Math.min(a, b)
   }
```

Comment: Can't speak for others, but the question does ask "How to find closest to 0."